# VIM search and insert newline if newline character found in middle of a line

Tags: regex, vim

This has been driving me nuts for a while now.  Actually, make that all damn night!!!

I have a file of contact information that is now only slightly mangled that I'm trying to fix in VIM.  The file has 13k lines so I really, REALLY don't want to have to manually fix this in the file.  I believe that the final issue I am having is that for some dumb reason many of the lines run together with the next line.  This is a csv file with newline characters separating the lines.  Unfortunately, there are maybe a couple of hundred lines where there is a newline character in the middle of should be two lines.

Here is an example of the file where this is occurring:

```
Freddy,Bauhof,fabaof@garbage.net,16126 Garbage Drive,Spring,TX,77      379,5555550440,M,1/1/14,14:23:57,256.241.24.29^@
Natasha,Moore,ndivy@garbage.com,3715 Garbage Rd,Louisville,KY,40218,5555553358,F,1/1/14,3:12:09,74.256.182.12^@MaryAnn,Haase,mahase@garbage.net,303 N       Garbage Rd,Norfolk,NE,68701,5555559031,M,12/31/13,7:20:21,69.256.211.147^@
Jonathan,Golden,jongolden@garbage.com,11 Garbage Dr,GlenHead,NY,115      45,5555556712,M,1/1/14,17:28:09,256.195.83.118^@
```

What I am trying to do is simply insert a newline/carraige return/whatever that will actually break the middle line into two after "12^@" and immediately before "MaryAnn".  Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Run this in vim `:%s/\^@\(\S\)/^@\r\1/g`.

It inserts a carriage return between `^@` and *not whitespace*.

```
Foo^@
Bar^@Baz^@
Qux^@
```

Becomes

```
Foo^@
Bar^@
Baz^@
Qux^@
```

Answer (score 1):

in **vim**:

this line would work:

```
%s/\^@\zs\ze\S/\r/g
```

if you are open to shell, **grep** could help you:

```
kent$  cat f
foo^@
foo2^@bar^@baz^@
blah^@

kent$  grep -oP '.*?\^@' f    
foo^@
foo2^@
bar^@
baz^@
blah^@
```

**sed** too:

```
kent$  sed -r 's/\^@(.)/^@\n\1/g' f
foo^@
foo2^@
bar^@
baz^@
blah^@
```